# How to loop through datagridview 1 and copy loop results to datagridview2 in a different form and DB table

Tags: .net, mysql, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I need help with this, I'll try to explain it in detail as much as I can.

Let's say in `Form1` I have a `Datagridview1 (DGV1)` which is `DataBound` to `Table1` with the columns `TransactionNumber(Double), FormName (varchar), Description(varchar), Posted(text)`.

In `Form2`, I have another `DGV2` which is `DataBound` to `Table2` with the columns `TransactionNumber(Double), Formname(VarChar), Description(VarChar), Quantity(Double)`.

In `Form1` I have `Textboxes` to add data to the Columns in `DGV1` and 2 Buttons `Add and Post`. When I click `Post` I want to loop through `DGV1` and find all the data with the given `TransactionNumber`, then copy those data to `DGV2` in `Form2`.

I really need help with this.. Any kind of tips or help would be greatly appreciated. Please and Thank You!

I still don't have codes for the Button Post as I'm still trying to figure out how to do this... I'm going to update this post with codes asap..

P.S. 
Still Learning

**NEW QUESTION BUT STILL RELATED TO THE ORIGINAL QUESTION**

**I tweaked your code, it now adds data.**

Could I also use this in an mdi form?

```
Dim occurences As New Dictionary(Of String, Double)

For Each DGVR As DataGridViewRow In Datagridview1.Rows

    If (Not DGVR.IsNewRow) Then

        If (occurences.ContainsKey(DGVR.Cells(1).Value.ToString())) Then

            occurences(DGVR.Cells(1).Value.ToString()) = Double.Parse(occurences(DGVR.Cells(1).Value.ToString()).ToString()) + Double.Parse(DGVR.Cells(4).Value.ToString())

        Else

            occurences.Add(DGVR.Cells(1).Value.ToString(), Double.Parse(DGVR.Cells(4).Value.ToString()))
        End If

    End If

Next


For Each KVP As KeyValuePair(Of String, Double) In occurences


    DataGridView2.Rows.Add(New Object() {KVP.Key, KVP.Value})

Next
```

Comment: Are you utilizing MDI Parent/child forms? It greatly dictates the type of solution you will get.

Comment: @KreepN to be honest, nope, I'm just really new with VB.Net and I've only been working with it for around a month or so.. Everything I've done so far is what I read from the net, Self studying, and help from people here... Would you be able to help me? I'm getting quite desperate... Thanks.

Comment: Anyone else willing to help??... I still haven't found a solution for this problem....

Comment: Is there any link exists between `Table1`(Form1) and `Table2`(Form2) ?

Comment: @NeverHopeless link?.. what kind of link are you asking?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't hate on me for this, as it is the best I could do in such a short time span:

http://www.fileswap.com/dl/KusycS0QTC/

Basically it's a project with an MDI parent form and two child forms. I have a DGV on each and I transfer the info from one form to the other. You will have to make the necessary edits to account for your setup, but it should be enough to give you an idea of how to go about what you're after.

EDIT:

Possible Changes:

```
     Dim _Name As String = ""
     Dim _Last As String = ""

      For Each xRow In MasterForm.oTransferRows
            _Name = xRow.Cells("GVName").Value.ToString()
            _Last = xRow.Cells("GVLast").Value.ToString()
```

**'Should the next line be insert into?**

```
            Dim _sqlInsert As String = String.Format("Insert testing(Name, LastName) Values  (@iName, @iLast)")
            Using conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server = localhost; Username= root; Password =; Database = test")
                Using cmd
                    With cmd
                        MsgBox("Connection Established")
                        .Connection = conn
                        .Parameters.Clear()
                        'Create Insert Query
                        .CommandText = _sqlInsert

                        .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@iName", _Name))
                        .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@iLast", _Last))
                    End With
                    Try
                        conn.Open()
                        Me.Validate()
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString())
                    End Try
                End Using
            End Using

        Next
```

---

[image]

Comment: hello, I know you must be very busy but I am struggling with another problem... same scenario, same names must be transfered to the other DGV, but this time instead of having the same name in 2 rows, I want it to have in 1 row but let's say in childform1, 1st row of same name has a `Quantity` of 10 and 2nd row of same name has a `Quantity` of 20, in childform 2 I want those in a single row but with a `Quantity` of 30, instead of having 2 rows. (description column in childform2 no longer needed)....(continued in next comment)

Comment: I know I must have an `if else` condition, and I do, I just don't know how to use `Update` query for looped datas.... I do have codes,, but didn't even bother to debug it since it's not complete... I don't know what lines to add....  I could do this for single rows being transfered but multiple rows being transfered just confuses me on how to do the math... and syntax....

Comment: also I do have a `Select` Query to get all the `Names` in childform2's table.

Comment: @AlexLuthor You could utilize LINQ to do some querying on the objects themselves. So lets say if you have 2 rows with the same Name, then you could query your row collection for distinct names and then sum their quantities into a new row collection with everything as you wish.

Comment: I see, hmm, is using LINQ hard? I kind of want to finish this problem within today. I found samples of LINQ here http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Official-Visual-Studio-f48134ec maybe I'll play with it a little and see. I still hope that you would be able to guide me if ever I'm missing a few spots. Thanks.

Comment: What is the difference between LINQ and my current way of Querying?

Comment: I like learning stuff and everything, but since I kind of want and need to get this problem solved, do you think maybe you could throw me a bone here..? even it's just a little piece?. I think I found a piece of code. I'll post it on my question... tell me if that kind of code is LINQ? Please and Thank You, I really appreciate your help, and I really need it.

Comment: @AlexLuthor That is linq but it may be too hard to use here. Check this project I made for you as it should get the point across: http://www.filedropper.com/linqexample1 . It loops through the rows and sums stuff for you. It may not be exactly what you want, but you can see what I'm trying to convey. If you are getting all the data from a DB, just write your query to group by the name itself. I'm off to bed :).

Comment: Thank you so much... yes my head actually hurts from trying to use LINQ maybe I really need time to study it, not like this rushing through it... Thanks once again....

Comment: it's on c# language?? hmmm ill just try to convert it.

Comment: I converted it to `VB.NET` but somehow mine doesn't work? perhaps I didn't get the syntax correctly... anyway edited the codes on my question..

Comment: I also managed to use this on MDI-p/c form, I'll try using this on queries tomorrow... and if I don't quite get it, please bear with me a little more, I'll come and ask you again... thank you so much! you're such a good programmer and person.

Comment: I wasn't able to codes for 2 days, my friends came home from the province, but for now I managed to filter the data that  I need to be added by using the codes from the previous sample... All I need now is to save that into the database.... here's the updated prj. http://www.fileswap.com/dl/NaIt6Ea0if/AlexLuthorLINQ.rar.html

Comment: I think I'll really need help with this one now, I'm not really sure how I would be able to save the filtered data and updated the database without creating a new row, so I can't pretty much use insert for the right?. (but in my original proj, I still need the insert into if the `FormName` isn't present yet.. but if it is, then I just need to update it's quantity... )

Comment: Okay now I also able to save it in the database, but the problem is, for ex I have 3 rows to add together, after clicking "Post" there are 2 rows of data being saved in my DB Table, 1st data has the sum of the first 2 rows. the 2nd row is the sum of all 3 rows. do you know why this happens? but ofcourse I'll check try to fix it myself aswell, while I wait for your reply... Thanks

Comment: http://www.fileswap.com/dl/oexx7Vkh3t/AlexLuthorLINQ.rar.html Here's the updated proj, all that's left is the problem I said.  :D

Comment: If your goal is to consolidate records, by deleting old records and then adding in the consolidated ones, you may wish to have that functionality build into an event. It would probably be the best way to do it as it would become very unmanageable to know which row you need to update and which ones to delete when they share a common name. Also, give me a sec on those duped rows.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20089/discussion-between-kreepn-and-alex-luthor)

Comment: I know it would be easier to delete old records, but I need those old records to act as a history... so yeah, I can't pretty much delete them. but I did disable my post buttons for records that are already posted...

Comment: Still not working,  I get the error `The given key was not present in the dictionary.` I'll try posting it into a new question.

Comment: here's the link to the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13560361/sum-the-values-from-datagridview1table1-and-save-it-to-datagridview2table2-u