# Looping through Datagridview in VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

Is there a way to loop through all the rows in a datagridview searching for all the rows with the same data in a column...

example: DGV1 has column `ID, TransID, Name, Desc`

let's say I have 3 rows in that DGV,

2 rows have the same `TransID = 1`

and the last row has a `TransID = 2`.

on my `Textbox1` i input "2" and press the button.

I want to loop through DGV1 to find all rows with the same TransID as the one I input in my textbox and copy those data to DGV2 in another form...

I asked a question earlier but no one seemed to be able to help me out, I really need help with this... To understand more about my predicament here's the link to my earlier question...

[How to loop through datagridview 1 and copy loop results to datagridview2 in a different form and DB table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466028/how-to-loop-through-datagridview-1-and-copy-loop-results-to-datagridview2-in-a-d#comment18421620_13466028)

---

@HaBouF here is what I have done from your codes, now I managed to filter the DGV

Database Name is `test` Table name for DGV1(Form1) is `tested` and Table name for DGV2(Form2) is `testing`

**Code**

`Dim ta As New testDataSetTableAdapters.testedTableAdapter`
 `Dim f2 As New Form2`

```
      dv.Table = TestDataSet.tested
      dv.RowFilter = "TransID LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"
      f2.DGV2.DataSource = dv
      f2.Show()
```

This code filters the data and shows it on `DGV2` but because we replace the datasource of `DGV2`, the existing data in DGV2 is temporarily removed  , How would I add the filtered data to table `testing(DGV2)`  without having to remove the existing data in `DGV2` **OR** directly adding it to the `Database` because I could manage just adding a `Refresh button` to get change the datasource of `DGV2` back to `testing`.

Comment: Show as the code that you used to fill the dgv1. It will help as to guide you to create similar code for the filtering you want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
I imagined that you have a datatable (dtOriginalData) that you fill it with the data and then you do:

```
dgv1.DataSource=dtOriginalData
```

What you need is to filter these data:

```
dtOriginalData.DefaultView.RowFilter = "TransID = " & textToFilter.Text

Dim MyNewTable As DataTable = dt.DefaultView.ToTable
```

What you need now is to open the new form and provide the filtered data:

```
dim f2 as new Form2
f2.DGV2.DataSource=MyNewTable
f2.Show
```

If the form2 is already opened and you want to update it , it is possible.

If you show as your code and explain better want exactly you want to achieve we will be able to help you more.

Comment: Thank you for replying, and sorry for being late on mine,  yes Im using a DataTable... all my datagrids are databound...  I see, I'll try to do this  tomorrow since I've been trying to do it for the whole day... and let you know by tomorrow if it works... one question though, you see, I think this code could work, but what if my DGV2 has existing data, and I just want to add the data from DGV1 to DGV2.... because this code would only filter DGV1 and replace DGV2 right? Thank you so much for your reply...

Comment: Yes , it is working as you described. If you need to add the filter data, show me your code, of how you databinding the dgv2. I need that to help you properly. We can do this in many ways

Comment: thank you, I'll try this right now and see if it's done as how I wished it to be. I'll get back to you with the results... Thank You so much for your time and effort.

Comment: It automatically creates the DGV2 when I drag the table from the datasource, so I'm not exactly sure of what you're asking. but this is the code that comes with it on formload      **Tested is the name of the table for DGV1 and Test is the name of the database.** `Me.TestedTableAdapter.Fill(Me.TestDataSet.tested)`

Comment: I managed to do it now with KreepN's help at my other question, But still thank you so much for your help and effort... trust me it wasn't wasted, I really needed help and everything. :D