# sum the values from Datagridview1(Table1) and save it to Datagridview2(Table2) Using Linq and MySql

Tags: .net, mysql, vb.net, winforms, linq

I am trying to sum the values from `Datagridview1(Table1)` and save it to `Datagridview2(Table2)`

both `DGVs` are `Databound` and both have the same 2 columns `Name, Quantity`.

On `Childform1(DGV1)` I have a `Textbox1` and a `Post` button.

The user must input a `Name` on `Textbox1` and click `Post`, then all the `Quantity` on `DGV1` must  be summed up that has the same `Name` as entered on `Textbox1`.

ex:

**Table1**

```
Name | Quantity
 a       10
 b        5
 a       10
 b        5
```

After pressing `POST` button

**Table 2**

```
Name | Quantity
 a        20
 b        10
```

**Codes**

```
    Dim occurences As New Dictionary(Of String, Double)
    Dim oTempObjects As New List(Of DataGridViewRow)

    MasterForm.oTransferRows = oTempObjects

    For Each xRow As DataGridViewRow In Datagridview1.Rows

        If (Not xRow.Cells("GVName").Value Is Nothing AndAlso xRow.Cells("GVName").Value.ToString() = TextBox1.Text) Then

            oTempObjects.Add(xRow)
        End If
    Next

    Dim _Name As New List(Of String)

    For Each xRows In MasterForm.oTransferRows

        _Name.Add("'" & xRows.Cells("GVName").Value.ToString() & "'")


        Dim inClause1 As String = String.Join(",", _Name.ToArray())
        Dim _sqlUpdate As String = String.Format("UPDATE tested SET Posted = @Posted WHERE Name IN ({0})", inClause1)

        Using _conn As New MySqlConnection("Server = localhost; Username= root; Password =; Database = test")
            Using _commm As New MySqlCommand()
                With _commm

                    .CommandText = _sqlUpdate
                    .Connection = _conn
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Posted", "Yes")

                End With
                Try

                    _conn.Open()
                    _commm.ExecuteNonQuery()

                Catch ex As MySqlException

                    MsgBox(ex.StackTrace.ToString)

                End Try

                _conn.Close()

            End Using
        End Using

        If (occurences.ContainsKey(xRows.Cells(1).Value.ToString())) Then

            occurences(xRows.Cells(1).Value.ToString()) = Double.Parse(occurences(xRows.Cells(1).Value.ToString()).ToString()) + Double.Parse(xRows.Cells(4).Value.ToString())

        Else

            occurences.Add(xRows.Cells(1).Value.ToString(), Double.Parse(xRows.Cells(4).Value.ToString()))
        End If

    Next

    For Each KVP As KeyValuePair(Of String, Double) In occurences
        oChildForm2.DataGridView2.Rows.Add(New Object() {KVP.Key, KVP.Value})
    Next

    Dim xlist As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Double)) = occurences.ToList

    For Each pair As KeyValuePair(Of String, Double) In occurences


        Dim oUpdateString = String.Format("Insert Into testing (Name, Quantity) VALUES (@iName, @iQty)")
        Using _conn As New MySqlConnection("Server = localhost; Username= root; Password =; Database = test")
            Using _commm As New MySqlCommand()
                With _commm

                    .CommandText = oUpdateString
                    .Connection = _conn
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@iName", pair.Key)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@iQty", pair.Value)
                End With
                Try

                    _conn.Open()
                    _commm.ExecuteNonQuery()

                Catch ex As MySqlException

                    MsgBox(ex.StackTrace.ToString)

                End Try

                _conn.Close()

            End Using
        End Using
    Next
```

This code only sums the same Name on the `DGV1` on the first click and saves it on `DGV2`.

but for example I add another data on `DGV1` with the same name,

I want the QUANTITY of the newly added data  to add to the current sum of the existing data on DGV2.

A little help with this too would be really awesome.**

Ex:

**TABLE 2**

```
Name | Quantity
 a       20
 b       10
```

Then I add data on Table 1

**Table1**

```
Name | Quantity
  a       20
  b       10
```

After Pressing Post

**Table2**

```
Name | Quantity
 a        40
 b        20
```

Comment: Here's what I've done so far it now adds and saves to the database the problem is when I close my Childform2(DGV2), I get an error No row can be added to a DataGridView control that does not have columns. Columns must be added first.

Comment: I'll take a look at it when I get a chance, shouldn't be too big of a problem to fix

Comment: How does the code look in the ChildForm.Closing sub? How does the code look around where you open ChildForm? Is it using ShowDialog or Show? Can you supply this code. We can't really find the error in a part of the code that seems to have nothing to do with the issue :/

Comment: @WozzeC 
 I open Childform2 with this 2 lines  ` oChildForm2.MdiParent = MasterForm` and   `oChildForm2.Show()`

Comment: I looked through the code and didn't see anything that would handle the forms being closed (that would also cause that error that is). You mind posting up your most recent project somewhere for me to see if it differs from mine, as I deleted some stuff last night as we talked.

Comment: @KreepN sorry for the late reply  i had lunch... it's pretty much the same except for the added codes trying to create a condition that if a data being added to DGV2 is already existing, it will just update it, if not it inserts a new one. but sure I'll post it on fileswap

Comment: @KreepN http://www.fileswap.com/dl/4Xo6Mn1yQT/AlexLuthorLINQ_(1).rar.html

Comment: @KreepN okay okay I got that closing error now... thanks :D hmmm, maybe a little help with the other problem? :D and the if I get that other problem down, I'm 90% done with the proj, and all the rest that remains are basic ones... :D

Comment: I'd assume you could use the DGV1_RowAdded event handler to get the row and add it to the DGV2.Rows collection. You would want to see if that name exists in DGV2 first and if it does, sum the quantity, or if it is now just add it.

Comment: @KreepN row added event and transfer the codes I used on how to insert or update the data?

Comment: Since DGV2 is the summation of DGV1, you would do a few things. First, check if the name is in DGV1, if so you know it will be an update and all you need to do is add that new quantity to the sum found in the SUM table. If it is not present in DGV1, it must not exist in the SUM table and therefore can be inserted, much like you are already doing.

Comment: @KreepN I cant do checking names on DGV1 because it would have similar names which aren't supposed to be posted yet, so I need to do the checking on the DGV2...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20153/discussion-between-kreepn-and-alex-luthor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Posted column when iterating through your rows to see if a row has been posted or not:

```
For Each xRows In MasterForm.oTransferRows.Where(Function(x) x.Cells("Posted").Value.ToString() = "No")
```

Then use the following psuedo-logic to write your code:

```
 'code to select data - select name from testing where name = 'Product1'
 'if(dr.Read())
 'update goes here
 'Else
 ' insert goes here
 'End if
```

Comment: hi there's an error on the update codes... I'll post it on chat.

Comment: @AlexLuthor Just got home, glad to hear you got it :)!

Comment: Probably wouldn't be able to do it without someone teaching me all these logic and syntax..

Comment: btw..... remember on my insert query we are only inserting 2 values.... what if I need to insert more than those 2 values(Key, Value) what if I have more than 2 data that needs to be inserted?

Comment: or should I use tuples now? instead of dictionary?

Comment: Continue to use dictionary and make the value an object that has all the properties you could ever wish to reference. Then use the key to get the object and use all the object's properties.

Comment: ohh ok so im going to like `Dim Object = "value1", "Value2", "value3"?

Comment: ok ok thanks... Ill try doing that, if this thing i'm doing right now doesn't work... :D

Comment: Hello I kind of need help again, it's about that object thing... I kind of need to have another value... but I'm quite confused on how to do this set the object on the dictionary and how to call what value I need from the object. I'll edit the codes on my question...

Comment: I just posted it as another question since this one is quite crowded. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677717/using-objects-in-a-dictionary-in-vb-net

Comment: @AlexLuthor You caught me as I was off to bed, I know what you're looking at doing and I'll point ya in the right direction. Make a class like you see in the above screenshot. You can then create objects like you see me doing and store those in the dictionary.

Comment: yup I know, I get the pic above, but how do I call the values needed in that object? ex: I have 2 values on an object, quantity and description. how do I get description from that object?