# Using Objects in a dictionary in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, winforms, dictionary, datagridview

This is how I Check if my dictionary `occurences`  already contains a key and a value and assign keys and values to it... but I need another value, so how do I use the object here?

```
Occurences.Add(xRows.Cells(4).Value.ToString(), Object)
```

Somehow like this:

```
occurences(xRows.Cells(4).Value.ToString()) = Double.Parse(occurences(xRows.Cells(4).Value.ToString()).ToString()) + <"1st object value here">)
```

But this is how I currently do it which only  has a key and a value but I need something like key, object which has (value, value), something like that:

Actual code:

```
If (occurences.ContainsKey(xRows.Cells(4).Value.ToString())) Then
    occurences(xRows.Cells(4).Value.ToString()) = Double.Parse(occurences(xRows.Cells(4).Value.ToString()).ToString()) + Double.Parse(xRows.Cells(7).Value.ToString())
Else
    occurences.Add(xRows.Cells(4).Value.ToString(), Double.Parse(xRows.Cells(7).Value.ToString()))
End If

Next
```

Then i have another code for insert where i need to use the 2nd value of the object.

```
Using commm As New MySqlCommand()
    With commm
         .Parameters.Clear()
         .Parameters.AddWithValue("@iBrnchCde", cmbBrnchCode.Text)
         .Parameters.AddWithValue("@iFCode", pair.Key)
         .Parameters.AddWithValue("@iDesc", <"2nd OBJECT VALUE HERE"> )
         .Parameters.AddWithValue("@iQty", pair.Value)
         .CommandText = oInsertString
         .Connection = _conn
         .CommandType = CommandType.Text
     End With
     commm.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

Comment: question does not make sense.

Comment: @MitchWheat I'm asking how to use objects in a dictionary, what part of it doesn't make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following:

```
Class CustomRowObject
    Public Property Name() As String
    Public Property Quantity() As Double
    Public Property Description() As String
End Class


If (occurences.ContainsKey(xRows.Cells(4).Value.ToString())) Then
    occurences(xRows.Cells(4).Value.ToString()).Quantity = Double.Parse(occurences(xRows.Cells(4).Value.ToString()).ToString()) + Double.Parse(xRows.Cells(7).Value.ToString())
Else
    occurences.Add(xRows.Cells(4).Value.ToString(),New CustomRowObject With { .Name = a.Cells("ProductName").Value.ToString(),.Description = .Cells("ProductDesc").Value.ToString(), .Quantity = a.Cells("Quantity").Value.ToString()})
End If

Next
```

Then reference it via `occurences("keynamegoeshere").Quantity` for use in your SQL.

Comment: Instead of repeating `xRows.Cells(4).Value.ToString()` 4 times, you could assign it to a variable and use that variable instead. The code would be way easier to read!

Comment: @KreepN http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13736693/formatexception-was-unhandled-vb-net a little help again, please. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question fully, but if I do I would suggest a different approach:

Why not make a class that holds your values, then add your class to the dictionary - or - create a dictionary of the class type:

```
Public myClass
    Public Code As String
    Public Desc as String
    ....
End Class

Dim myClassInstance as New myClass
'initialize fields
occurences.Add(key, myClassInstance)
```

To retrieve get the value as an object and use `if typeof value is myclass then` - if you choose object as type for the dictionary.

If you choose object you can store different classes and types of course, but the cost is the casting. If possible make a dictionary of the type you will use to avoid casting.

```
Private myDictionary as New Dictionary(Of String, myClass)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yup I'm trying to do that now thanks :D