# FormatException was unhandled vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, exception, datagridview

This Might be a long question but please do bear with me a little.

I have a `Datagridview1` on `Form1` with the columns `BranchCode("cells(2) ,FormCode("cells(3)")), Quantity("cells(5)")`

Now Let's say this is how it looks like

**DGV1**

```
 BranchCode | FormCode | Quantity
     001         Frm1       10
     002         Frm2      -10
     001         Frm1       20
```

Now on DGV2 let's say I have an data with the same branch code and form code

**DGV2**

```
BranchCode | FormCode | Quantity
    001        Frm1        50
    002        Frm2        50
```

Now the code below loops through `DGV1` then sums up all the `Quantity` with the same  `FormCode and BranchCode` before adding it to `DGV2`

Ex: **DGV1 results**

```
BranchCode | FormCode | Quantity
    001        Frm1        30
    002        Frm2       -10
```

Then After adding it to DGV2 this would be the result

**DGV 2 Results**

```
BranchCode | FormCode | Quantity
    001        Frm1        80
    002        Frm2        40
```

**CODE**

```
For Each xRows In MDIAdjustment.oTransferRows.Where(Function(x) x.Cells("GVPosted").Value.ToString() = "No")

      If (occurences.ContainsKey(xRows.Cells(3).Value.ToString())) Then

          occurences(xRows.Cells(3).Value.ToString()).Quantity = Double.Parse(occurences(xRows.Cells(3).Value.ToString()).ToString()) + Double.Parse(xRows.Cells(5).Value.ToString())

               Else

                    occurences.Add(xRows.Cells(3).Value.ToString(), New CustomValues2 With {.Code = xRows.Cells(3).Value.ToString(), .Branch = xRows.Cells(2).Value.ToString(), .Description = xRows.Cells(4).Value.ToString(), .Quantity = Double.Parse(xRows.Cells(5).Value.ToString()) })  

               End If

     Next
```

Declaration of `occurences dictionary`

```
Dim occurences As New Dictionary(Of String, CustomValues2)

Class CustomValues2 

Public Property Code() As String 
Public Property Branch() As String 
Public Property Description() As String 
Public Property Quantity() As Double 

End Class
```

The question is, when I compute using only positive integers, I have no problem, but when I start to add negative numbers I get an error on this line

```
 occurences(xRows.Cells(3).Value.ToString()).Quantity = Double.Parse(occurences(xRows.Cells(3).Value.ToString()).ToString()) + Double.Parse(xRows.Cells(5).Value.ToString())
```

Saying `FormatException was Unhandled" Input string was not in a correct format`

Sorry For the long Post, I've tried to do things but they don't remove the error.

Comment: I would suggest that you unbox the code a bit, not only will it be faster, but easier to track bugs. - What is the signature on the occurences function? Could you post its code.

Comment: Alex, I think I know what it is, hit me up : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20673/alex22

Comment: @AbdiasSoftware sorry for the late reply, occurences is a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your error line to :

```
occurences(xRows.Cells(3).Value.ToString()).Quantity = occurences(xRows.Cells(3).Value.ToString()).Quantity + Double.Parse(xRows.Cells(5).Value.ToString())
```

You need to add to the quantity property, so you need to fetch its current value.

Comment: another question, just to avoid human errors, I have a `SeriesFrom` and a `Series To` column on my database... 2 Tables have them... How could I check my those 2 tables if I'm entering a number see if already exists in the database? i got a few codes I just don't know how to apply the logic. I selected the needed columns like this `"SELECT incomingdeliveries.SeriesFrom, incomingdeliveries.SeriesTo, outgoingdeliveries.SeriesFrom, outgoingdeliveries.SeriesTo FROM incomingdeliveries, outgoingdeliveries WHERE incomingdeliveries.FormCode = @iCode AND outgoingdeliveries.FormCode = @iCode "`

Comment: I also have an if else loop to see if the the number I entered is already equal to or between the 2 numbers... I just don't know what to use to compare values... I do get the logic, I have problems with the syntax to use.. I'll post it on chat. and if you have time please check :)

Comment: @AlexLuthor I'd guess you would want to get the distinct values from those columns, store them somewhere, and use the collection to program some code that will act differently based on if it is or is not in the collection. Post it up somewhere (in a question works) so I can check it out when I have a few minutes.

Comment: it's really simple if all I need to do is compare numbers, but I also have to check between those numbers....

Comment: or do you think I could just do this SET `@value = txtFrom.text; @value2 = txtTo.text
SELECT Table1.SeriesFrom, Table1.SeriesTo, Table2.SeriesFrom, Table2.SeriesTo FROM table1, Table2 WHERE Table1.Seriesfrom > @value AND @value <= Table1.Seriesto AND Table1.Seriesfrom > @value2 AND @value2 <= Table1.Seriesto AND Table2.Seriesfrom > @value AND @value <= Table2.Seriesto AND Table2.Seriesfrom > @value2 AND @value2 <= Table2.Seriesto `

Comment: Then if results are 0 then add.?

Comment: @AlexLuthor That doesn't seem like too bad of an idea. Have you tried it?

Comment: yep, I've been trying it so far so good. but I didn't do it in one query, I seperated it in elseif loops

Comment: do you know the syntax to check if dr.read() doesn't have anyvalues...? I need it for my elseif...

Comment: cause when I use elseif isdbnull(dr) then.... (codes)... end if it goes straight to end if without running the codes inside it.

Comment: @AlexLuthor IsDBNull is for data, not objects. If(dr.Read() = null) should work.

Comment: I used if dr.read() = 0 and it works. think it's good enough as if(dr.read() = null) ???

Comment: @AlexLuthor I wasn't aware that it returned 0 if it did not read anything. I think you may actually be reading data, becasue I use If(dr.read() is nothing) at work all the time in vb.net.

Comment: it gives an error...(dr.Read() Is Nothing) is opperator does not accept operands of type boolean

Comment: @AlexLuthor If (Not IsNothing(dr)) Then - Try that.

Comment: if I use that then the it will be the opposite right? (Not IsNothing(dr)) = saying if dr isn't nothing, which means if it isn't empty... :D what I need is, if dr is empty haha,

Comment: This is a short question, and you're really fast to reply than others, I get an error `cannot perform '=' operation on system.double and system.string vb.net`. you see I have 2 textboxes to filter my DGV, and i have to compare 2 numbers, but when I erase the number on one of the textboxes the error comes out. how do I stop that from happening?? :D

Comment: Nvm, I got it :P hahaha added this  `If txtSearch.Text = "" Then txtSearch.Text = "0"   ElseIf txtTo.Text = "" Then txtTo.Text = "0" End If`